# How to insert Heading 1 and 2 list numbers in headers in Word, like 12.27?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm going for two level chapter numbers inserted in the headers. I already have the headings stylized. What could be the field code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a STYLEREF field and add the \n switch to show the paragraph number for your style rather than the heading text.